# How can we use our own customised embedding with WordMoverDistance?

Tags: stanford-nlp, gensim, word2vec, wmd

To use WMD we need some word embeddings. For this example a pre-trained embedding provided by Gensim '**word2vec-google-news-300**' is used.

Below is code snippet:

```
import gensim.downloader as api
model = api.load('word2vec-google-news-300')
distance = model.wmdistance(sent1, sent2)
```

How can I use my own customised embedding in place of that ,How can I load that in model?
for ex: Embedding somewhat looks like - {text:1-D NumPy array}

Comment: Do you want to *train* your own embedding, from your training texts, or do you already have your own customized embedding available? (If the latter, what format is it in?)

Comment: I have my own customized embedding it looks like -- {'Today is rainy day':[0.03,0.98,0.77...........]}

Comment: That looks like an embedding for the whole string `'Today is rainy day'`, not a set of individual word-embeddings, which is what a WMD calculation would require. (And, it's not in a typical format.) So, you'd need word-vectors instead to use WMD.